# like button not working from aritical 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

#### Like button not working from article 2

**Note: Like button works well for Article 1.**
Article 2 like button is not toggled. 
I am using toggleClass to toogle fontawesome icon.
The code is given below.

Please help me to solve this problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Like Button</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
    .well{
     background-color: white;
    }
    body{
     background-color: #f7f7f7;
    }
     .love{
      font-size: 20px ! important;
     }
     .love:hover{
      cursor: pointer;
     }
     .fa-heart-o{
      color: red;
     }
     .fa-heart{
      color: red;
     }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
  <h3>
   Like button not working from Artical 2
  </h3>
  <div class="well"><h4>Artical 1</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, qui aspernatur accusantium! Molestiae, cum cupiditate nam optio dignissimos magnam velit, perspiciatis amet qui aut nobis, quisquam, laudantium vitae eos ipsam.</p>
   <hr>
<span id="love" class="love"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Like</span>
  </div>

  <div class="well"><h4>Artical 2</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, qui aspernatur accusantium! Molestiae, cum cupiditate nam optio dignissimos magnam velit, perspiciatis amet qui aut nobis, quisquam, laudantium vitae eos ipsam.</p>
  <hr>
  <span id="love" class="love"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Like</span></div>

  <div class="well"><h4>Artical 3</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, qui aspernatur accusantium! Molestiae, cum cupiditate nam optio dignissimos magnam velit, perspiciatis amet qui aut nobis, quisquam, laudantium vitae eos ipsam.</p>
   <hr>
  <span id="love" class="love"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Like</span></div>

  <div class="well"><h4>Artical 4</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, qui aspernatur accusantium! Mo2estiae, cum cupiditate nam optio dignissimos magnam velit, perspiciatis amet qui aut nobis, quisquam, laudantium vitae eos ipsam.</p>
   <hr>
  <span id="love" class="love"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Like</span></div>

  <div class="well"><h4>Artical 5</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore, qui aspernatur accusantium! Mo2estiae, cum cupiditate nam optio dignissimos magnam velit, perspiciatis amet qui aut nobis, quisquam, laudantium vitae eos ipsam.</p>
   <hr>
  <span id="love" class="love"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Like</span></div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary f2r Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#love").click(function(){
      
       $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart');
    });
     });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little change in your script 
Use class and not id and it works fine

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".love").click(function(){
            $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Glad this helps you

Comment: Will this code work fine with Ajax & Php. when get liked people data from database using Php and Ajax. But every user can like post only once how to do that

Comment: You need to understand your flow for this and have to manage user login and its like , otherwise you cannot find out who had like this article once or second time! much better if ask a new question for this

Answer (score 1):

[image]Use `$(document).on("click", "#love", function() {`
 instead of `$("#love").click(function(){`. It is working fine for all button's click event.

After this it will look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on("click", "#love", function() {
            $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart');
         });
    });
</script>
```

I am attaching screenshot of working output.PFA

Comment: welcome. But I would like to know which method you have used? changing syntax of click event or using the class name?

Comment: Both method works fine for me. Now I am using class name. What is the different between both methods. I am make a social networking site. I am going to use this like button on SNS.

Comment: The method I have told you is refreshes your click event for every time click event has been triggered. And you can triggered this event by using class name also; just the way you did it. its depending on developer he has to triggered event based on class name or id of control. If you required same event to be triggered for multiple controls so you can use class name. If you are triggering event for just one control so there you can use id of control because id will be unique for each control.

Comment: Which method is the best method for me?

Comment: In your case you have given same id to all span tag. and "id" has to be  unique. As I have already explained you its on developer choice and based on this condition that If you required same event to be triggered for multiple controls so you can use class name. If you are triggering event for just one control so there you can use id of control because id will be unique for each control. I would suggest ,you can remove same id you have used in your code for span tag and maintain classes for triggering same event for multiple control.